# Java Bucket Sort of Elements in another Array

Tags: java, sorting, bucket

I just recently started learning java and today I learned how I can do the so called selection sort. I have been trying for the last 3 hours to do a bucket sort, but there are some parts which I don't know how to code. ***Important*** : I am learning java completely by myself with a book. I am not a student and I am doing this as a hobby. I already googled everything I could think of and I didn't find a solution. I don't have a teacher or anybody who I can ask, so yea, any help would be appreciated!

Code:

```
private int[] bucketSort() {
    int[]bucket=new int[maxSize+1];
    int[]sortedElements = new int[elementaros.length];
    for(int i=0; i<elementaros.length;i++) {
        bucket[elementaros[i]]++; //it says that I can't convert from Car to int. How can I add the elements of array elemenators to bucket?
    }
    int outPos = 0;
    for (int j = 0; j < bucket.length; j++){
        for (int k = 0; k < bucket[i]; k++){
            sortedElements[outPos++] = i;
        }
    }
    return bucket; 
}
```

**The idea of the code** :

I have an array elements of type `Car`(`Car` is another class of my program). It looks like this - `Car[] elementaros`. `int maxSize` shows the maximum number of administrable `Car` objects.  What I want to do is the following - I want to sort the elements in the `elementaros` array alphabetically. I would really really appreciate it if somebody has the time to show me how this would function with an example code or would just give me some tips. As I said - I have nobody who I can ask.

Comment: What is the definition of `elementaros`? Is it `Car[]`? I think you just need `bucket[i]++`.

Comment: `elementaros[i]` returns i-th item of `elementaros` (of type `Car`), but you pass it as `bucket`'s index (that should be `int` in range 0-`maxSize`)

Comment: Question is : do you want to stay with a home made algorithm to do this or are you open to some other solution ? (like using Java streams to sort your Car array)

Comment: @GenoChen Car[]elementaros. elementaros is from type Car[](Car is another class which I have)

Comment: @MadJlzz I'd like to do it with a home made algorithm if possible.

Comment: @barbsan unfortunately I can't understand what do you mean with ''pass it as bucket's index''. Do you mean that I should write only bucket[i]++? If that's not the case,could you please show me?

Comment: `bucket[elementaros[i]]++` = `bucket[index]++` where `index = elementaros[i]`

Comment: @barbsan I tried it and now the error is the following - "the left-hand sign of an assignment must be a variable". Damn xD

Comment: it's not suggested solution but explanation of what you did in that line

Comment: @barbsan ohhh I see now! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

<s>A selection sort is a combination of searching and sorting.</s>

The principle is quite simple but I always prefer a diagram than huge explanations.

[image]

Start a pointer at the beginning of your `unsorted` array. Then, for each value of the array, search for the minimum value (or search for the alphabeticaly ordered car) in your array and switch the position of the founded `Car` with the pointer (which is a `Car` too)

Then you can advance the pointer to the next element of the array.

Here is a basic implementation to do this

```
public static Car[] doSelectionSort(Car[] elementaros) {

    for (int i = 0; i < elementaros.length - 1; i++) {
        int index = i;
        for (int j = i + 1; j < elementaros.length; j++) {
            if (elementaros[j].getName().compareTo(elementaros[index].getName()) < 0) {
                index = j;
            }
        }

        Car nextOrderedCar = elementaros[index];
        elementaros[index] = elementaros[i];
        elementaros[i] = nextOrderedCar;

    }

    return elementaros;

}
```

Just for example sake, I imagine your object of type `Car` has a name that we could use for the comparison.

***UPDATE 1:***

I have read your initial question too quickly and it leds me to answer a total different sorting algorithm. My bad.

I found an implementation here that does the trick:

- [williamfiset bucket sort](https://github.com/williamfiset/Algorithms/blob/master/com/williamfiset/algorithms/sorting/BucketSort.java)
- [explanation of bucket sort plus different implementation](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/bucket-sort-2/)

Hope this helps.

Comment: Is Car[] elementaros in your case the bucket? In my case I have a Car[]elementaros (elementaros is the array from type Car. Car is another class which I have). In "private void int[] bucketSort()" I'd like to sort Car[]elementaros' elements with bucket sort(with another array - buckets[]). I understood the basic bucket sort, it's pretty logical. However I have a problem when I try to sort the elements of another array with a bucket[] array as I have shown in the example.

Comment: @KirimidkoTuhlev I do not unterstand what you are saying but basically, `elementaros` is the array you want to sort out. Plus I am modifying directly the passed array index and not using a `tmp` array like you are.

Comment: No problem :D That is my problem right now... I don't know how to properly form this in bucket sort and I googled everything I could possibly think of :D

Comment: @KirimidkoTuhlev found some new resources to help you moving forward.

Comment: Thanks for your time, buddy. Unfortunately I can't figure it out. Based on what I want to do I just can't figure it out : (

Comment: What I am trying to do right now is the following - I want to put the objects from type Car(who are in another class) in buckets. I can't find an example that does that and can't figure it out.

Comment: In all the examples its always the same - they declare a new array. They don't get the objects from an already existing array from another class. That's what I can't figure out how to do - my array is from type Car, the arrays in the examples are all from type int. So some of the things don't work as they are shown.

Comment: At least I progressed with my code :D The main problem is here :                    
 for (int i=0; elementaros.length; i++) {  //elementaros is the array from type Car///
                  bucket[elementaros[i]]++; //it just doesn't allow me to do that because of this error - "Type mismatch -  cannot convert from Car to int"

Comment: I think you are missing core concept of OOP. Is it possible to post all of your project on GitHub so I can have a look on your full code and try to explain you ?